# String to Query for All Records in Table

Tags: php, mysql, query-string

When I pull each leadstatus individually (?leadstatus=New, ?leadstatus=Hot, etc.) they work, but when trying to get All, I can't seem to get it to work. The default on the page is New leads as you can see.

```
`$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contacttype IN ('New','Buyer','Seller','Buyer / Seller','Investor') AND leadstatus = 'New' ORDER BY date DESC";

    if(isset($_GET['leadstatus']) && in_array($_GET['leadstatus'], array('New', 'Hot', 'Warm', 'Cold', 'Rejected', 'Closed')))
    {      
    $status = $_GET['leadstatus'];   
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE leadstatus = '".$status."' ORDER BY contacts.date DESC";  
    }`
```

Here are some of the strings I've tried with no luck:

```
?leadstatus=New&leadstatus=Hot&leadstatus=Warm&leadstatus=Rejected&leadstatus=Cold - Only pulls last listed, which is Cold

?leadstatus[]=New&leadstatus=[]Hot&leadstatus[]=Warm&leadstatus[]=Rejected&leadstatus[]=Cold - Returns default, which is New

?leadstatus=New&Hot&Warm&Rejected&Cold
```

- Returns default, which is New

Comment: Why not just make the where statement conditional?  If status indicates that you want all records, remove the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['leadstatus']) && $_GET['leadstatus'] == "all") {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY contacts.date DESC";  
} else if (in_array($_GET['leadstatus'], array('New', 'Hot', 'Warm', 'Cold', 'Rejected', 'Closed'))) {      
    $status = $_GET['leadstatus'];   
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE leadstatus = '".$status."' ORDER BY contacts.date DESC";  
}
```

Then, make leadstatus = all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_GET['leadstatus']) && in_array($_GET['leadstatus'], array('New', 'Hot', 'Warm', 'Cold', 'Rejected', 'Closed')))
{      
  $status = $_GET['leadstatus'];   
  if(!empty($status)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE leadstatus = '".$status."' ORDER BY contacts.date DESC";  
  } else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY contacts.date DESC"; 
  }
}`
```

However, may I also suggest that you use a parameterized query?  You are wide open to a SQL Injection attack here.

Comment: it will be behind a login screen, so shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: It always matters!  injection attacks give the attacker a LOT of power very easily.  for example, what if I put in a request that said `?leadstatus='; DROP TABLE contacts; --`  Relevant: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should match multiple conditions, allowing you to mix-and match several at a time, rather than 1 or all.

```
$status = join(',',$_GET['leadstatus']); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE leadstatus IN($status) ORDER BY contacts.date DESC";
```